# No key-comparison sorting algorithm

Tags: sorting

On this [webpage](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/sortcomp.html) I can read:

> A few special case algorithms (one example is mentioned in
>   Programming Pearls) can sort certain data sets faster than
>   O(n*log(n)). These algorithms are not based on comparing the items
>   being sorted and rely on tricks. It has been shown that no
>   key-comparison algorithm can perform better than O(n*log(n)).

It's the first time I hear about **non-comparison algorithms**. Could anybody give me an example of one of those algorithms and explain better how they solve the sorting problem faster then O(nlog(n))? What kind of tricks the author of that webpage is talking about?

Any link to papers or other good source are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: NOTE: Edited to removed the word "no" from "It's the first time I hear about *no* key-comparison algorithms." - although it's key to answering the question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the edit. It's not the first time I hear about the, so much famous, key-comparison algorithms. It's the first time that I hear about the: "no-key-comparison alg".

Comment: Edited again with the terminology used by NPE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let's get the terminology straight:

1. *Key comparison* algorithms can't do better than `O(n logn)`.
2. There exist other -- *non-comparison* -- algorithms that, given certain assumptions about the data, can do better than `O(n logn)`. [Bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) is one such example.

To give an intuitive example of the second class, let's say you know that your input array consists entirely of zeroes and ones. You could iterate over the array, counting the number of zeroes and ones. Let's call the final counts `n0` and `n1`. You then iterate over the output array, writing out `n0` zeroes followed by `n1` ones. This is an `O(n)` sorting algorithm.

It has been possible to come up with a linear-time algorithm for this problem only because we exploit the special structure of the data. This is in contrast to *key comparison* algorithms, which are general-purpose. Such algorithms don't need to know anything about the data, except for one thing: they need to know how to compare the sorting keys of any two elements. In other words, given any two elements, they need to know which should come first in the sorted array.

The price of being able to sort anything in any way imaginable using just one algorithm is that no such algorithm can hope to do better than `O(n logn)` on average.

Comment: So, we can say that the "tricks" mentioned in the quote in my question are strongly linked to the possibility to do "certain assumptions about the data"?

Comment: @LuigiMassaGallerano: Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes non comparison sorting usually takes O(n) an example of these sorting algorithms are the [Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) and [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)